# Dealing with long lists of number in pygame

Tags: python, list, pygame

I am just learning python and have started making a game using pygame.
In my game I have a list that contains all of the obstacles that the player must over come in each of the levels. Although this list quickly became very big and has started to take up many lines of my project.

I was wondering if I should have a dedicated text file that contains this list and import it into my project or if there is a better way of doing this. I know this is a kind of vague questions but I was just wondering if importing a long list into my project could be a good way about going with this problem.

I really hope someone knows what to do because I am not quite sure and I would really appreciate someone else's opinion on the matter.

Comment: This is really a matter of opinion (thus not generally suitable for SO), and it seems like you already know what would be the best option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it depends on how many obstacles you got or if you want it to look neat and tidy then yeah. if your not doing `obstacles = [obstacle(100,100,24,50), obstacle(100,100,24,50), obstacle(100,100,24,50), obstacle(100,100,24,50), obstacle(100,100,24,50)...]` then do that and see if it still looks like a lot. its no better or worse. Completely up to you

Comment: thank you, I think I probably will put the data in a text file because I feel like that would make it tidier.